# Can I make this jQuery tooltip stay on when my cursor is over it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tipsy

http://onehackoranother.com/projects/jquery/tipsy/

Let's say I hover over something.  And the tooltip appears above the link.  When I move my mouse to the tooltip, it disappears.  Is there a way to keep it up?

The reason I'm asking this is because I want to put a button inside the tooltip. I don't want it to go away when I go click the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the cluetip plugin. ie sticky option in that from below link -

http://plugins.learningjquery.com/cluetip/demo/

This plugin is easy to use and lot of configuration options are available as well.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the following code jquery.tipsy.js file

Starting from line 61 onwards

```
function() {
    $.data(this, 'cancel.tipsy', false);
    var self = this;
    setTimeout(function() {
        if ($.data(this, 'cancel.tipsy')) return;

        var tip = $.data(self, 'active.tipsy');
        if (opts.fade) {
            tip.stop().fadeOut(function() { 
                $(this).remove();   
            });
        } else {
            tip.remove();
        }
}, 100); // <- change 100 to 1000
```

Change "100" to "1000" on the indicated line.

Answer (score 1):

This functionality is not built-in, but it's not so hard to add it yourself by manually showing and hiding tipsy (using `trigger: 'manual'` and `$.hover()`). The code below, while a bit lengthy, should work fine.

```
$('.some-class-name').each(function () {

    var me = this,
        timer = null,
        visible = false;

    function leave() {
        // We add a 100 ms timeout to give the user a little time
        // moving the cursor to/from the tipsy object
        timer = setTimeout(function () {
            $(me).tipsy('hide');
            visible = false;
        }, 100);
    }

    function enter() {
        if (visible) {
            clearTimeout(timer);
        } else {
            $(me).tipsy('show');
            // The .tipsy object is destroyed every time it is hidden,
            // so we need to add our listener every time its shown
            $('.tipsy').hover(enter, leave);
            visible = true;
        }
    }

    $(this).tipsy({html: true, trigger: 'manual'});
    $(this).hover(enter, leave);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the plug in documentation you can set a delay before the tool tip disappears, try:

```
$("#element").tipsy({ delayOut: 2000 }); // delay before hiding tooltip (ms)
```

**See other configuration options here:**

http://onehackoranother.com/projects/jquery/tipsy/#options

Comment: delayOut and delayIn are not working for me. They are not taken into account. Any idea why? thanks